# Output Firefox JSON data

Tags: php, json, firefox, bookmarks

Is it possible to output specific JSON data (exported from Firefox bookmarks) using PHP.

This is the code which I have so far, it will re-encode the data as Firefox doesn't export it in the correct UTF-8 way. I also remove the trailing , from the end of the file.

```
<?php
// Read the file blah blah
$hFile = "../uploads/james.json";
$hFile = file_get_contents($hFile);
$hFile = utf8_encode($hFile);
// Remove the trailing comma because Firefox is lazy!!!!
$hFile = substr($hFile, 0, strlen($hFile)-3) . "]}";

$hDec = json_decode(fixEncoding($hFile));

foreach($hDec['uri'] as $hURI) {
    // Output here
}

// Fixes the encoding to UTF-8
function fixEncoding($in_str) {
    $cur_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($in_str);
    if($cur_encoding == "UTF-8" && mb_check_encoding($in_str,"UTF-8")){
        return $in_str;
    }else{
        return utf8_encode($in_str);
    }
}
?>
```

I have been unable to get any output apart from the whole data, using var_dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As VolkerK says, you have to strip the commas before both `]` *and* `}`:

```
// ... row 7
// Remove the trailing comma because Firefox is lazy
$hFile = preg_replace('/,\s*([\]}])/m', '$1', $hFile);

// ... or using str_replace
$hFile = str_replace(',]', ']', str_replace(',}', '}', $hFile));
```

But, the way you are trying to access the URI's of the bookmarks (which I assume is what you are trying to do) wouldn't work.

Recheck the format/schema of the file.

Comment: Could you also give an example of outputting all URIS? I don't see what I missed.

Comment: If you examine the json or the var_dump() of $hDec you see that it's not a list of URI:s and names. You have to go thru all of the children for the root entry, then all of their children etc etc. The children then have a uri value that you can do stuff with or filter by.

Answer (score 3):

While json_decode() is able to decode

```
<?php
$c = '{"title":""}';
$bookmarks = json_decode($c);
var_dump($bookmarks);
```

it fails on

```
$c = '{"title":"",}';
```

The "empty" element at the end throws the parser off.
And that's exactly what my bookmarks.json looks like

```
{"title":"", ... "children":[]},]}
```

edit: [json.org](http://www.json.org/) links to [Comparison of php json libraries](http://gggeek.altervista.org/sw/article_20061113.html). And according to their comparison chart e.g. [zend json](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.html) should be able to parse firefox' bookmark.json. Haven't tested it though.

edit2: why not simply test it....?
Yes, zend json is able to parse the unmodified bookmarks.json

```
require 'Zend/Json.php';
```

$encodedValue = file_get_contents('Bookmarks 2009-05-24.json');
$phpNative = Zend_Json::decode($encodedValue);
var_dump($phpNative);prints

```
array(7) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["id"]=>
...
      ["children"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So is there any way this is possible?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the use of libraries, but if this does end out being the only option I shall look into it.